# Use the full name instead of the user name as author of articles

Tags: nodes, users

I'm coming to Drupal from Joomla.  To be honest, Drupal is a little more daunting.

I simply wish to have the author's name appear in the articles (ie, written by RealName) instead of the default (written by username).

I already have the real name field created, and can display the real name if I click on user info.

Any idea how I can have "written by realname" on articles?

Answer (score 5):

There's a module for that - [RealName](http://drupal.org/project/realname)

> The RealName module allows the administrator to choose fields from the user profile that will be used to add a "real name" element (method) to a user object. Hook_user is used to automatically add this to any user object that is loaded. It will also optionally set all nodes and comments to show this name.

EDIT - since your new to Drupal you might want to checkout - http://drupalmodules.com/ - great way of finding modules that you might need.

Comment: A difference between Drupal and Joomla: there is ALWAYS a module for that :)

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the advantage of using RealName over having users use their "Real name" as their user name, is that knowing which user names are available for brute-force password attempts, becomes much harder.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is nothing preventing you for using usernames as realnames, as you can use spaces by default in username, but you got some options tho.

You could create a author field your self on the node type, however this forces you to type it in manualy.

You could make a template for the nodetype, printing the profile field yourself.

I will thought encourage you to have a look at either views (http://drupal.org/project/views) or panels (http://drupal.org/project/panels), which gives you a lot of control of the output.

If you are new to drupal, start with Views, this will solve your problem almost out of the box by override the node/% page.

With panelizer (http://drupal.org/project/panelizer) you can define default layouts for each nodetypes, using fields of choice.